How can call vim's built-in javascriptcomplete for html file?
I can call javascript's tab complete for html this way.
cd  .vim/bundle/vim-snippets/snippets
mv html.snippets  html.snippets.bak
cp javascript/javascript.snippets html.snippets

Set tab key for complete.
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsEnableSnipMate=1

Now i can call javascript complete in html file,edit test.html ,type for and press tab key,
for (let i = 0, len = Things.length; i < len; i++) {
    
}

I can get javacript's for expansion in html file.
So i want to call Vim’s built-in javascriptcomplete when to edit html file.
Set  omnifunc for javascript in .vimrc:
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType javascript inoremap  .  <C-X><C-O>

Eidt test.js ,type document and press . two times,it shows:

Add two lines in my .vimrc:
autocmd FileType html set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType html inoremap  .  <C-X><C-O>

Edit test.html,type document and press . two times,

How can call vim's built-in javascriptcomplete for html file?

The first part of your question is about "snippet expansion", which is provided by third-party plugins and completely unrelated to omnicompletion.
The second part, where you enable omnicompletion for javascript buffers, is pointless because Vim already does that for you. Moreover, triggering completion each time you insert a . in your buffer is not a very bright idea. You should either:

stick with the default <C-x><C-o>,
use a more unique key combination (FWIW, I use ,, for that),
use a third-party plugin that will handle the complexity for you.

The third part, where you want to type JavaScript in an HTML file, is weird because who would do that? Moreover, Vim already enables JavaScript omnicompletion for you in <script></script> tags in html buffers so… you basically have nothing to do to write HTML and JavaScript except adding these lines in your vimrc:
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

This question and the previous one, where you tried to use a third-party plugin without installing it make it look like you are going way too fast, skipping important steps.
You should follow the user manual, at least until chapter 32, before trying all those shenanigans: :help user-manual.
